# $\lfloor na\rfloor+\lfloor nb\rfloor=\lfloor nc\rfloor+\lfloor nd\rfloor$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

If $a,b,c,d$ are positive irrational number such that
$$a+b=c+d$$

Prove that

$$\lfloor na\rfloor+\lfloor nb\rfloor=\lfloor nc\rfloor+\lfloor nd\rfloor\quad\forall \,\,n\in\mathbb N$$

My working:

$$\left(\lfloor na\rfloor+\lfloor nb\rfloor\right)-\left(\lfloor nc\rfloor+\lfloor nd\rfloor\right)=\left(\{nc\}+\{nd\}\right)-\left(\{na\}+\{nb\}\right)$$
$$\implies \left(\{nc\}+\{nd\}\right)-\left(\{na\}+\{nb\}\right)=\pm1,0$$

Comment: I don't understand the question exactly, what is $n$?  Letting $a=b=0.610110111011110\dots$, letting $c=0.010110111011110\dots$ and letting $d = 1.2101101110\dots$ (*just picking an easy irrational to do arithmetic with*), and letting $n=1$ we would have $a+b=c+d=1.220220222022220222220\dots$ and that $\lfloor na\rfloor + \lfloor nb\rfloor = 0+0 = 0$ but on the RHS this would have resulted in $0+1$... not equal.

Comment: I edited $n$ is a positive integer

Comment: $n=1$ *is* a positive integer. Maybe instead of the floor function, you want the *round off* function?

Comment: And?  You are wishing to show that $\lfloor na\rfloor + \lfloor nb\rfloor$ is exactly equal to $\lfloor nc\rfloor + \lfloor nd\rfloor$?  Or are you wanting to show that they are at most one apart?  My counterexample shows that the claim as it is currently written is false.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim what would even be the "round off function" here?  If round to the nearest integer then my example would have the LHS be $1+1=2$ while the RHS would still be $0+1=1$ and be unequal that way

Comment: I got this problem from Mathematical Gems III page 181 by Ross Honsberger. It seams problem is not correct.

Comment: Check that the phrasing is *exactly* the same... no missing words, no missing symbols... maybe include a picture of the question.  Similar questions I've seen in the past might have been asking for "*suppose that $\lfloor na\rfloor +\dots$*" and this is a part of the assumptions and they are asking you to conclude something else, not that this line should be the conclusion that is proven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an image of the book in question:

[image]

By looking at the proposed solution and by considering my counterexample in the comments above, we recognize that there must be something wrong.  In particular, there appears to be an additional missing assumption that was left out of the problem statement... namely that $a+b$ is an integer.

Without that assumption, the line "*$[na]+[nb]=nk - (\{na\}+\{nb\})$ showing that $(\{na\}+\{nb\})$ is an integer*" is unjustified, but by including that $k$ is an integer then this would have been okay.  Everything else that follows in the book's proof would have been justified.

Again, as written without that assumption the claim is false.  A counterexample is $a=b=0.6101101110\dots$ and $c=0.0101101110\dots, d=1.2101101110\dots$ and considering $n=1$